# Swagger UI not accessible following WebDeploy

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, webdeploy

Been struggling with this for a bit and looking for some advice.

I have .NET 5.0 api web application with swagger ui that works locally (https://localhost:5001/swagger/index.html), but when I deploy via WebDeploy it says it's successful but I cannot access the web page (404)

I was expecting to be able to access it at https://mysite/swagger/index.html

I have an accompanying project that uses the api that I am deploying with WebDeploy with virtually the same configuration and it works ok.

The API is up and running, I just can't get to the web interface.